# Communicate between Labview and Twincat with TCP/IP : FB_SocketCloseAll errId=6

Tags: tcp, twincat

I am using beckhoff example to communicate with TCP/IP, the mais code is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM0x9.png)

But error is always True and when I get into FB, I saw FB_SocketCloseAll.errId=6

I searched for that error code and I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEX5r.png)
As there is no port parameter in this function I think my issue is around ADS server or something like that but I don't know how to check if ADS is started and how to make it reachable.
Both Labview server and Twincat TCP client are on the same machine this is why I use 127.0.0.1 as string connection.
Thanks a lot for your help.
JG30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [install TF6310](https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/products/automation/twincat/tfxxxx-twincat-3-functions/tf6xxx-connectivity/tf6310.html) on the target device (the device doing the TCP/IP communication, in other words the PLC). Target port not found means that it can't find the software.

Comment: Thank you very much, it solves my issue. As I saw TCP/IP functions block I thought TCP was installed, but it was only TCP libray and not TCP runtime in the PLC...